# add missing header to dataframe first column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm reading a json response with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_json(url,orient="index")
```

The returned dataframe is six columns but the first column doesn't have header. How can I add a header to this column? This is the first column. I don't want to have to rename the other columns...

Comment: could you add a sample output to your dataframe? I think df.rename should work for you.

Comment: I think this is the index.., **step 1**: Check `df.index` and `df.columns`. **Setp 2**. **2.1** If it is the index use: `df = df.rename_axis(index = enter name here)`, if you want  convert it to column use `df = df.reset_index()`. **2.2** else if it is a column then you can do `df.columns = [the name of the first columns] + df.columns[1:].tolist()`

Comment: right. so I didn't understand correctly the issue I had. It was related to the index. Should I delete my question?